# Which Pad token in Google-News Word2vec Pre-trained Model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm using the pre-trained model from Google to do word embedding. What kind of string should I give to the model to receive and array full of zeros? I need to pad some sentences and I need an array of zeros to embed the padding. Maybe should I create the array of zeros instead of the model?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you've loaded the `GoogleNews` vector set, via some word2vec library like gensim, you can look up words that are in that set, and get back vectors. If you want an all-zeros vector instead, you'd just create that instead, with no model involvement – for example via `numpy.zeros()`. But typical uses of word-vectors won't require all-zeros vectors as any sort of padding – so it would be rare to be mixing any such vectors into other word2vec-based text processing.

Comment: I'm given a sequence like `['how', 'are', 'you', '<PAD>', '<PAD>']` that has to be embedded. How can I say to gensim that '<PAD>' tokens have to be treated like padding tokens?

Comment: In my experience, it's more common to drop unknown/rare/uninteresting words – *not* add synthetic `<PAD>` tokens. Occasionally, projects add some sort of plug/pad tokens during training, but then there are actual synthetic word-tokens inside the model, matching whatever substitution they chose to make, with trained-up (non-zero) word-vectors under that lookup key. I don't think the `GoogleNews` set has such synthetic words, and even if it did, they might not be suitable to use for your purposes.

Comment: Words not contained in the word embedding vocabulary has been already dropped. The problem is that sentences have different lengths....do you know a different way (instead of padding) to have all sentences have the same length?

Comment: If you need to turn variable-length texts into vectors of the same size, you might use a method like averaging all word-vectors together, or some other method to learn per-text vectors (like `Doc2Vec` or some deep/recurrent text-modeling algorithm). It's atypical to force all sentences to be the same length with arbitrarily-many garbage padding tokens – if you think you need to do that, you'd need to explain further why. Why would you need to "say to gensim that '<PAD>' tokens have to be treated like padding tokens"? To what gensim class would you be sending such fixed-length inputs?